# Apache references wrong httpd.conf after Mac OS X Sierra upgrade

Tags: macos, apache, httpd.conf

I've recently upgraded to Mac OS X Sierra and it has totally shafted my apache/PHP setup. Having wasted most of the morning, I've finally found the *actual* httpd.conf file that is being referenced at **/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.2/httpd.conf**, whereas the file I need to be using is at **/etc/apache2/httpd.conf**.

How can I tell Apache to use the version I was successfully using before the update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about MacOS version, but with any binary of httpd you use the parameter -f, as in:

```
httpd -k start -f /path/to/conf
```

In most cases you need to load envvars file in your environment, this file is in bin directory in an official install of httpd and generally adds HTTPD lib directory  to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
So briefly

```
. /path/to/httpd/bin/envvars
httpd -k start -f /path/to/conf
```

Or `apachectl` which is an official script which refers to both to make your life easier.

Comment: I managed to solve it by killing off a number of other apache instances that I wasn't aware were running, and now the file I expected to work is working. But your answer does solve my initial question, so thank you.